# How to update weights with TensorFlow Eager Execution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

So I tried TensorFlow's eager execution and my implementation of it wasn't successful. I used `gradient.tape`, and while the program runs, there is no visible update in any of the weights. I've seen some sample algorithms and tutorials using `optimizer.apply_gradients()` in order to update all variables, but I'm assuming I'm not using it properly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

# emabling eager execution
tf.enable_eager_execution()

# establishing hyperparameters
LEARNING_RATE = 20
TRAINING_ITERATIONS = 3

# establishing all LABLES
LABELS = tf.constant(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))
# print(LABELS)

# stub statment for input
init = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))

# declare and intialize all weights
weight1 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 3]))
bias1 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))
weight2 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 2]))
bias2 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))
weight3 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 3]))
bias3 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))
weight4 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 2]))
bias4 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))
weight5 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3]))
bias5 = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))

VARIABLES = [weight1, bias1, weight2, bias2, weight3, bias3, weight4, bias4, weight5, bias5]


def thanouseEyes(input):  # nn model aka: Thanouse's Eyes
    layerResult = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(weight1, input) + bias1)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(weight2, input) + bias2)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(weight3, input) + bias3)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(weight4, input) + bias4)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(weight5, input) + bias5)
    return layerResult


# Begin training and update variables
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:  # gradient calculation
    for i in range(TRAINING_ITERATIONS):
        COST = tf.reduce_sum(LABELS - thanouseEyes(init))
        GRADIENTS = tape.gradient(COST, VARIABLES)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(GRADIENTS, VARIABLES))
        print(weight1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `optimizer` seems fine, however the computation defined by `thanouseEyes()` will always return [1., 1., 1.] irrespective of the variables, thus the gradients are always 0 and thus the variables will never be updated (`print(thanouseEyes(init))` and `print(GRADIENTS)` should demonstrate that).

Digging in a bit more, `tf.nn.softmax` is applied to `x = tf.matmul(weight5, input) + bias5` which has a shape of [3, 1]. So the `tf.nn.softmax(x)` is effectively computing `[softmax(x[0]), softmax(x[1]), softmax(x[2])]` as [`tf.nn.softmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) applies (by default) on the last axis of the input. `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` are vectors with one element so `softmax(x[i])` will always be 1.0.

Hope that helps.

Some additional points unrelated to your question that you may be interested in:

- As of TensorFlow 1.11, you don't need the `tf.contrib.eager` module in your program. Replace all occurrences of `tfe` with `tf` (i.e., `tf.Variable` instead of `tfe.Variable`) and you'll get the same result
- Computation performed inside the context of a `GradientTape` is "recorded", i.e., it holds on to intermediate tensors so that gradients can be computed later on. Long story short, you'd want to move the `GradientTape` inside the loop body:

-

```
for i in range(TRAINING_ITERATIONS):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        COST = tf.reduce_sum(LABELS - thanouseEyes(init))
    GRADIENTS = tape.gradient(COST, VARIABLES)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(GRADIENTS, VARIABLES))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I changed the statement `tf.nn.softmax` to apply on the final most axis, so now it's actually printing out appropriate values. But, I'm still retrieving zeros on all gradient computations. Would you like me to start a new thread, or would it be okay if I messaged you? Also, thanks for the additional aid, it really helped:)

Comment: Zero gradients still suggest that the output (or loss function) is not dependent on the variables, so I'd encourage you to dig into the details of the computation. If you're still stuck, then may make sense to start a new question with more detail. Best of luck!